# How to get rid of component duplication, the only difference is loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

There are two files in my project, **SelectGradientTheme.js** and **SelectColorsTheme.js**. I can not calmly continue to work, observing that the contents of these two files are repeated, it is unbearable. The only difference is the array that these components receive, and so 99% of the code is repeated

**SelectGradientTheme.js**

```
export default function SelectGradientTheme(props) {
    const groupSize = 3;

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    const rows = GradientThemes.map(function (col, index) {
        return <SelectThemeContent {...props} col={col} key={index} selectedIndex={selectedIndex} index={index} setBorder={setBorder}/>
    }).reduce(function (r, element, index) {
        index % groupSize === 0 && r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(element);
        return r;
    }, []).map(function (rowContent, index) {
        return <div key={index} className="SelectThemePictures_Separator">{rowContent}</div>;
    });
    return <div className="container">{rows}</div>;
};
```

**SelectColorsTheme.js**

```
export default function SelectColorsTheme(props) {

    const groupSize = 3;

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    const rows = SideBarColors.map(function (col, index) {
        return <SelectThemeContent {...props} col={col} key={index} selectedIndex={selectedIndex} index={index} setBorder={setBorder}/>
    }).reduce(function (r, element, index) {
        index % groupSize === 0 && r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(element);
        return r;
    }, []).map(function (rowContent, index) {
        return <div key={index} className="SelectThemePictures_Separator">{rowContent}</div>;
    });
    return <div className="container">{rows}</div>;
};
```

Please tell me how to get rid of duplicate code

Comment: Is the diff `GradientThemes` versus `SideBarColors`? What are these? Could these just be passed/consumed as a prop?

Comment: Create one Component and pass object (SideBarColors, GradientThemes) and chang your loop like this this.props.myObject.map(...)

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that gets the themes (`GradientThemes` or `SideBarColors`), and returns a component:

```
const createSelectTheme = themes => props => {
    const groupSize = 3;

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    const rows = themes.map(function (col, index) {
        return <SelectThemeContent {...props} col={col} key={index} selectedIndex={selectedIndex} index={index} setBorder={setBorder}/>
    }).reduce(function (r, element, index) {
        index % groupSize === 0 && r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(element);
        return r;
    }, []).map(function (rowContent, index) {
        return <div key={index} className="SelectThemePictures_Separator">{rowContent}</div>;
    });
    return <div className="container">{rows}</div>;
};
```

To create each component pass the respective theme's array:

```
const SelectGradientTheme = createSelectTheme(GradientThemes);

const SelectColorsTheme = createSelectTheme(SideBarColors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the array as a prop to the compoent

```
export default function Theme(props) {

    const groupSize = 3;

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    const rows = props.myArray.map(function (col, index) {
        return <SelectThemeContent {...props} col={col} key={index} selectedIndex={selectedIndex} index={index} setBorder={setBorder}/>
    }).reduce(function (r, element, index) {
        index % groupSize === 0 && r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(element);
        return r;
    }, []).map(function (rowContent, index) {
        return <div key={index} className="SelectThemePictures_Separator">{rowContent}</div>;
    });
    return <div className="container">{rows}</div>;
};
```

And to pass the array.

```
<Theme myArray={SideBarColors} />
<Theme myArray={GradientThemes} />
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what should I get through the props?

Comment: You can pass your array as a props.